# Windows 8.1 system restore from win8 DVD issue

Tags: windows-8, bsod

Right now my windows 8.1 installation boots into BSOD with error "CRITICAL_SERVICE_FAILED" probably after a failed windows update

When running system restore from the window 8 DVD , the restoration fails with error message suggest that i have an Anti-virus open and block the operation.

I also try to boot on safe mode but instead the "System Recovery" operation starts and im not able to boot on safe mode. EDIT: After disabling the System Restore i still cannot go into Safe Mode with error 0x00000001

EDIT:
Issue may appeared after running "disk cleanup" and deleting 7gb of "junk" data. Looks like those where windows 8 update files

Any ideas how to get the pc up and running?

Comment: Is just screwing it and factory reinstalling off the table?

Comment: i really want to avoid it tbh ....

Comment: Maybe if you have a command line you can (assuming the pathname is no more than 254 characters) migrate your user profile to a USB or external.